# How to notify List component that its row item height has changed and make the row rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-virtualized

I have a `react-virtualized` List, each `item` in the `rows` have an `expand button`, when the button is clicked the height of the row changes and it expands and show more info.

the issue here is, after the button got clicked the inner `Grid` (`ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer`) CSS height property is not updating or the `Gid` is not re-rendering/notified of the changes in row height

What should I do to make it rerender the row everytime the row item height gets updated?

here is my main `index.js` file:

```
import React, {
  cloneElement,
  Component,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  createRef,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";

import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import {
  List,
  AutoSizer,
  CellMeasurer,
  CellMeasurerCache
} from "react-virtualized";

import Expander from "./expander.js";

export default function Test() {
  // List data as an array of strings
  let list = [
    "Brian Vaughn",
    "Bob Smith",
    "Someone Else",
    "I hate making up names"
    // And so on...
  ];

  const listRef = useRef();

  const expander = (
    <Expander onChanged={() => listRef.current?.list?.forceUpdateGrid()} />
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <AutoSizer
      // disableWidth
      // disableHeight
      >
        {({ width, height }) => {
          return (
            <List
              ref={listRef}
              className="List"
              autoHeight
              width={800}
              height={400}
              rowCount={list.length}
              rowHeight={30}
              rowRenderer={({ index, isScrolling, key, style }) => (
                <div className="Row" key={key} style={style}>
                  {list[index]}
                  {expander}
                </div>
              )}
            />
          );
        }}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my `expander.js` file ( Row Component ):

```
import React, {
  cloneElement,
  Component,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  createRef,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Expander(props) {
  // State : Declare
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const renderMoreText = () => {
    if (isClicked) {
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 200 }}>
          long lorem ipsum{" "}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.onChanged();
  }, [isClicked]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsClicked(true);
        }}
      >
        {" "}
        Expand more text{" "}
      </button>
      {renderMoreText()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-pond-xq1csq?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with react-virtualized, but reading the docs you could make use of the List `onChanged` event together with Expanders `recomputeRowHeights()`.

Updated sandbox (quick and dirty): https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-cookies-omi14k?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: hi, I tried implementing the `onChanged` into my own code, the default `ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer` get updated each time `onChanged` is called (https://ibb.co/hC8RD7H), but the `ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer` for my own custom list only updates once (https://ibb.co/WKrPdjj) do you know why?

Comment: here is my new sandbox if that helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-microservice-itv3sb?file=/components/albums/results/Box.js:274-347